# batch process to sync opportunity contact roles with custom object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

since opportunity contact roles doesnt have an option to write triggers, i am using a batch process to sync it with my custom object.

Opp and OpportunityContactRole are related with oppid, Project and customobj are related by projectid

Project and Opp are related with oppid. Project have lookup for opp ids.

The question that i have is

1. If it was just inserting from a opportunitycontactRole into a empty custom object, then i could loop through all the opportunitycontactRole and create a new record for customobj and replacing the oppid with projectid from a map of oppid and projectid. But if there is a record already present and if there is a change made to the contact only then how would i check and update it? Also if there were some records in customobj i am stuck on how to go about doing it

Any pointer would be great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. i found the solution myself... Just in case somebody had a similar requirement.

Created a new field in customobject to hold the id of contact role

Loop through all the active project, 
capture all the opp ids from there into a set
capture all project ids into another set
capture all projects into map with oppid and project id

Loop through all records in customobject for the projects from the projectid set
capture all contactrole ids into set
create a map of contactroleid and customobject and add the records there (Mapcontactrole)

Loop through all oppcontactrole for all the opps captured in the oppidset
Check if contactroleid is present in the mapcontactrole
if yes, Check if there is any change in fields, if there are changes make the update
and add this record into a new list of customobject
else
add it to list of custom object

upsert the new list of customobject